calculate percentage of completeness hierarchically on a tree
I have a table where I store tasks for a Gantt chart. Each task has a start date, a duration and a percentage of completeness.
This is an extract of my table for a single project



id
text
start_date
duration
progress
parent
sortorder
project




1
DT Next phase 1
2023-02-23 00:00:00
281
0
0
1
1


2
PREPARE
2023-02-23 00:00:00
19
0
1
2
1


3
Prepare
2023-02-23 00:00:00
19
0
2
3
1


4
EXPLORE
2023-03-23 00:00:00
122
0.9
1
4
1


5
Bbp definition
2023-03-23 00:00:00
113
1
4
5
1


6
Bbp approval
2023-08-01 00:00:00
5
0
4
6
1


7
REALIZE
2023-07-23 00:00:00
153
0.5
1
7
1


8
System config
2023-08-01 00:00:00
122
0.2
7
8
1


9
Configure sys
2023-08-01 00:00:00
145
0.4
7
9
1


10
Unit test
2023-07-23 00:00:00
123
0
7
10
1


11
Custom dev
2023-07-23 00:00:00
3
0
7
11
1


12
Func spec
2023-07-23 00:00:00
62
0
7
12
1


13
Tech spec
2023-07-23 00:00:00
73
0
7
13
1


14
Unit test
2023-07-23 00:00:00
92
0
7
14
1


15
Data Migration
2023-08-23 00:00:00
122
0
7
15
1


16
Mock 1
2023-08-23 00:00:00
31
0
15
16
1


17
Mock 2
2023-09-23 00:00:00
30
0
15
17
1


18
Mock 3
2023-10-23 00:00:00
31
0
15
18
1



This table is used to display the GANTT graph and the user can update the progress of each activity. What I don't have so far is to update the progress of the parents up to the top level and I am trying to build a trigger for that.
Assume that the user will set row 18 progress to 0.6 (60%). It means that the progress is of 31 x 0.6 days = 18.6 days. Row 18 parent is 15 so I need to do duration * progress of each row with parent = 15 and get the total: 31 x 0 + 30 x 0+ 31 x 0.6=18.6
Then I need to take duration on row 15 and do 18.6/122 = 0.15 that is the progress of row 15. So I need to update row 15 with progress = 0.15.
Then, row 15 parent is 7 so I have to do the same with all the rows with parent 7 and update row 7.
Row 7 parent is 1 and again the same math. Is it possible with one or more query in a Mysql Trigger?
The table will contain data for different projects and I need to do the update only on the records that match the same project id as the row I started with

parent = 0 ? There's no such ID. That would prevent you from defining the foreign key. Use null instead.

@TheImpaler parent is not a FK and parent=0 just tells my js code what is the node to start with designing the tree. I don’t want to change how my library works but add the trigger to update the data. There are several other use cases to account for but this is the first to start with

Did I understand correctly that you can change the values of the end vertices of the graph?

This is possible using a MySQL trigger. I could not find a table name, so in my query I just called it table. Replace this with your own table name.
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER update_parent_progress 
AFTER UPDATE ON table
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE total_duration DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE total_progress DECIMAL(10,2);
    DECLARE parent_id INT;

    -- Get the parent ID of the updated row
    SELECT parent INTO parent_id FROM table WHERE id = NEW.parent;

    -- Calculate the total duration and progress of child tasks
    SELECT SUM(duration * progress) INTO total_duration
    FROM table
    WHERE parent = parent_id AND project = NEW.project;

    -- Calculate the total progress of child tasks
    SELECT SUM(duration) INTO total_progress
    FROM table
    WHERE parent = parent_id AND project = NEW.project;

    -- Update the progress of the parent task
    UPDATE table
    SET progress = total_duration / total_progress
    WHERE id = parent_id AND project = NEW.project;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

I hope this is what you need.
